# How to download HTML content from infinite scrolling website which works based on put request...?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-shell

## Issue with downloading HTML Content

I am working on an academic project which requires data gathering from Yahoo answers page for category 
"Politics and Government".I am able to extract the data in JSON format using the code below can

someone please help me out to download HTML content of the complete web page

```
import json
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

category_dict = {'Arts&Humanities': '396545012', 'Beauty&Style': '396545144', 'Business&Finance': '396545013',
                 'Cars&Transportation': '396545311', 'Computers&Internet': '396545660',
                 'ConsumerElectronics': '396545014',
                 'DiningOut': '396545327', 'Education&Reference': '396545015', 'Entertainment&Music': '396545016',
                 'Environment': '396545451', 'Family&RelationShips': '396545433', 'Food&Drink': '396545367',
                 'Games&Recreation': '396545019', 'Health': '396545018', 'Home&Garden': '396545394',
                 'LocalBusinesses': '396545401', 'News&Events': '396545439', 'Pets': '396545443',
                 'Politics&Government': '396545444', 'Pregnancy&Parenting': '396546046',
                 'Science&Mathematics': '396545122',
                 'SocialScience': '396545301', 'Society&Culture': '396545454', 'Sports': '396545213',
                 'Travel': '396545469',
                 'YahooProducts': '396546089'
                 }


class YahooAnswers(scrapy.Spider):


name = "test"

    # API URL
    api_url = 'https://answers.yahoo.com/_reservice_/'

    # API headers
    api_headers = {
        'content-type': 'application/json',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'
    }

    # custom headers
    headers = {
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.61 Safari/537.36'
    }

    # HTTP PUT request payload
    payload = {
        "type": "CALL_RESERVICE",
        "payload": {
            # change the category ID to retrieve proper questions
            # e.g. you have URL: https://answers.yahoo.com/dir/index/discover?sid=396545443
            # so you need to look at "?sid=396545443" string query parameter
            # and extract the number 396545443 to use it as the "categoryId" below
            "categoryId": "396545444",
            "lang": "en-US",
            "count": 20,
            "offset": "pc00~p:0"
        },
        "reservice": {
            "name": "FETCH_DISCOVER_STREAMS_END",
            "start": "FETCH_DISCOVER_STREAMS_START",
            "state": "CREATED"
        }
    }

    # data offset
    data_offset = 0

    # crawler'a entry point
    def start_requests(self):
        # make HTTP PUT request to API URL
        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=self.api_url,
            method='PUT',
            headers=self.api_headers,
            body=json.dumps(self.payload),
            callback=self.parse
        )

    # parse questions callback method
    def parse(self, response):
        json_data = json.loads(response.text)
        filename = "NewsandEvents.txt"
        # check if next bunch of data available
        if json_data['payload']['canLoadMore']:
            # update data offset
            self.data_offset += 20

            # update payload offset
            self.payload['payload']['offset'] = 'pc' + str(self.data_offset) + '~p:0'

            # crawl next bunch of data
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=self.api_url,
                method='PUT',
                headers=self.api_headers,
                body=json.dumps(self.payload),
                callback=self.parse
            )
            with open(filename, 'a') as f:
                f.write(response.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Scenario #1** - You don't need the page HTML, you need the **data**.

Now that you have `JSON`, you have everything that you need.
In your `parse` method, just read the values from JSON to create a dictionary and yield them. You can output to CSV, JSON etc.

Your code would look something like:

```
for questions in json_data['payload']['questions']:
  yield {
    'title':question['title'],
    'detail':question['detail'],
    # More attributes here

  }
 # check if next bunch of data available ...
 # Rest of your logic to fetch next page
```

**Scenario #2** - You actually need the HTML of the page, you will have to use something to render like Selenium or splash.

Hope it helps